# Array type name print

Tags: c#

I'm trying to print the derived types of the values assigned to each employee in the array. How do I go about doing so without getting the entire project name included. salariedEmployee instead of Module11.salariedEmployee.

```
//create 4 element Employee array
Employee[] employees = new Employee[4];

//initialize array with Employees of derived types
employees[0] = salariedEmployee;
employees[1] = hourlyEmployee;
employees[2] = commissionEmployee;
employees[3] = basePlusCommissionEmployee;

Console.WriteLine("Employees processed polymorphically:\n");

//generically process each element in array employees
foreach(Employee currentEmployee in employees)
{
    Console.WriteLine(currentEmployee); //invokes ToString()

    //determine whether element is a BasePlusCommissionEmployee
    if(currentEmployee is BasePlusCommissionEmployee)
    {
        //downcast employee reference to BasePlusEmployee reference
        BasePlusCommissionEmployee employee = (BasePlusCommissionEmployee) currentEmployee; //downcast

        employee.BaseSalary *= 1.10M;
        Console.WriteLine("New base salary with 10% increase is {0:C}", employee.BaseSalary);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Earned {0:C}\n", currentEmployee.Earnings());
}

//get type name of each object in employees array
for (int j = 0; j < employees.Length; j++)
    Console.WriteLine("Employee {0} is a {1}", j, employees[j].GetType());
```

Comment: The whole point of inheritance is to not treat different types differently.  The calling code should just call virtual methods which do different things for different implementations, if they need to do different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
Console.WriteLine("Employee {0} is a {1}", j, employees[j].GetType());
```

To

```
Console.WriteLine("Employee {0} is a {1}", j, employees[j].GetType().Name);
```

Or (depending on your needs)

```
Console.WriteLine("Employee {0} is a {1}", j, employees[j].GetType().FullName);
```